# How to configure the network interface with a dynamic range of IP addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

I am new to networking, so please bear with me. I have two network interfaces. One network interface is connected to the external world. Another network interface 'p3p1' is what I want to use for programming my gadget i.e. NFS use. I want that other interface 'p3p1' to be configured with the dhcp server running on my pc. Thus, once my gadget connects to the interface p3p1, it gets the IP assigned by the DHCP server running on my PC. How can I do so? Is it possible?

Here is my attempt to configure the p3p1 interface.

```
I have the following dhpcd.conf file.

    #
    # DHCP Server Configuration file.
    #   see /usr/share/doc/dhcp*/dhcpd.conf.sample
    #   see dhcpd.conf(5) man page


    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
        subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option routers 10.0.0.1;
        range 10.0.0.5 10.0.0.15;
        }

However, I get the following errors while running the dhcpd. 

    ]# dhcpd 
    Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.4-P2
    Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
    All rights reserved.
    For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
    Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
    Wrote 0 leases to leases file.

    No subnet declaration for em1 (136.170.195.17).
    ** Ignoring requests on em1.  If this is not what
       you want, please write a subnet declaration
       in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
       to which interface em1 is attached. **


    Not configured to listen on any interfaces!

    This version of ISC DHCP is based on the release available
    on ftp.isc.org.  Features have been added and other changes
    have been made to the base software release in order to make
    it work better with this distribution.

    Please report for this software via the Red Hat Bugzilla site:
        http://bugzilla.redhat.com

    exiting.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the interface p3p1 with an IP address within the range of the DHCP server's subnet and make sure the interface is up when you start the DHCP server.

Comment: I am using FC19. Thus,I changed it to vi /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd
# Command line options here
DHCPDARGS="em1"
dhcpd_flags="em1"   ------> But the problem is same.

Comment: You may need to also create a subnet that is in the same subnet as the adapter's current ip address.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I am not getting it.

Comment: What are you trying to do / why are you doing it ?

Comment: I am trying to make a dhcp server here. This way, the other computers connected on this network will get the IP address assigned from my machine.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI Everyone who has viewed your question knows you are trying to create a dhcp server.  Please [edit] your question and describe in more detail your environment or we cannot help you further.  Explain why your IP address is public.  Explain the network layout.  Explain why you want to do what you are doing.

Comment: I have re-worded my question, please respond.

Answer (score 1):

You are running DHCP on interface `em1` which has IP address 136.170.195.17

The range you have provided DHCP to use is 10.0.0.0/24.  The IP address of em1 is not in this range, and so cannot be used on interface em1.

If your server has an interface in the 10.0.0.1 then this is the interface you should have dhcp running.

If you only have one interface in the server, then it either needs the address changed from 136.170.195.17 to something in 10.0.0.x or you need to add a 10.0.0.x address as a secondary address to em1.

What your question doesn't contain is any information about what you are trying to achieve or the configuration of your network and server, so it is difficult to provide any guidance.

Comment: I am trying to run dhcpd service on my pc.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI That doesn't add any additional information to what we already know from the question.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI  This answer satisfies the question, it explains how to solve the problem. What you should try to do is [edit] your question to provide more information so that you might get a better answer.

Comment: I have reworded my question, please do respond. Also, please remove my ban on posting questions if you liked my re-worded question.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI We don't control your ban - stop asking everyone on all your questions to lift your ban.

Comment: Yeah, I do understand, but I have revamped my question. I have just told that I am new to networking, so please ignore if my questions are not intelligent. Also, As I know there are no stupid questions. One will always learn a few more details when discussed.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI Your comment below says your interface is em1 and above you say p3p1.  Please update your /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd to so that it has p3p1 interface specified.